# Looking for Reporting GUI (Portal) web based for Mysql with high-end look and feel

Tags: mysql, user-interface, reporting

I have a mysql database as a "Data Ware House".
I have a lot of ready to go queries that I want to run as reports.

So what I need is a web based reporting GUI (Portal) that Can get configuration of:
query, fields titles and report description.

So when ever I want to add a report I just need to provide a query and the reporting gui will have that report in the menu.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [myDBR](http://mydbr.com) reporting tool. You can generate good looking reports very easily from your existing queries. myDBR is also able to genereate charts and drill-down reports in a few seconds.